# Google's Link Checker script returning URL errors that are not broken

Tags: google-ads-script

I have implemented Google's Link Checker Script into my account and, although it runs without errors, it frequently flag URLs having issues but when manually checked, those URLs are working fine.

When we receive an email saying that there is an error found, we go and check the Google sheets where the scripts would log the errors and it is usually "Address not Available" . It then logs the actual URLs and the related ad groups, keywords etc.

I don't really understand why the script keeps flagging the url as not available when it is working fine.

Link to the script -> https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/link-checker

thanks.

The main issue here is that we wrote a custom script that will check if any url erros has occurred as a result of the link checker and, if so, we would pause the related ad groups and we do not want to be pausing adgroups without a genuine reason.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothting to do with programming

Comment: The questions links to Google Ads Scripts docs, not to Google Apps Script docs. The question doesn't include enough details. It's very likely that the is no programming error at at all. You shoul to start by to spend time to understand how the script works and how to verify if it's working correctly.